# How to open Master page by clicking my own button in the datail page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Usually when creating a MasterDetailPage, a toobar with hamburger button are created automatically, I need to create a normal button in middle of the screen and the master page would open and swipe automatically from the left without seeing the toolbar with its hamburger button, I wanna hide the toolbar entirly. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property IsPresented. Personally I used MessagingCenter to Hide or Show menu as below

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<HideMenu>(this, AppConstants.MessagingKeys.HideMenu, (sender) =>
            {
                IsPresented = false;
            });
```

Comment: I actually found the solution now by adding this line to the detail page
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); 
and now im gonna add IsPresented to the button

Answer (score 0):

I have set the following code in the buttonClick function which is located in the detail page

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "OpenMenu");
```

Then I used the follwing code in the Master page

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "OpenMenu", (sender) => {
            IsPresented = true;
        });
```

and to hide the toolbar in the detail page I used :

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```